# Python SQL Query on PostgreSQL DB hosted ElepantSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have an issue to run my SQL queries on a Postgres ElephantSql hosted:
This is my code to connect (except dynamo, user, password which are replaced by XXX

```
DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://YYYY:ZZZZ@drona.db.elephantsql.com:5432/YYYY'
# ----------------------------  CONNECT ELEPHANT DB
def ElephantConnect():

    up.uses_netloc.append("postgres")
    url = up.urlparse(DATABASE_URL)
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='YYYY',
                            user='YYYY',
                            password='ZZZZ',
                            host='drona.db.elephantsql.com',
                            port='5432'
                            )

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE notes(id integer primary key, body text, title text);")
    #conn.commit()

    # conn.close()
    return conn
```

this code seems to connect well to db

My issue is when I want to delete a table:

```
def update(df, table_name, deleteYes= 'Yes'):

    conn = ElephantConnect()
    db = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
    cursor =conn.cursor()

    if deleteYes == 'Yes': # delete
        queryCount = "SELECT count(*) FROM {};".format(table_name)

        queryDelete = "DELETE FROM {};".format(table_name)
        count = db.execute(queryCount)
        rows_before = count.fetchone()[0]
        try:
            db.execute(queryDelete)

            logging.info('Deleted {} rows into table {}'.format(rows_before, table_name))
        except:
            logging.info('Deleted error into table {}'.format(table_name))
    else:
        pass
```

It seems when I run db.execute(queryDelete), it goes to the exception.
I have no message of error. But the query with count data is working...
thanks

Comment: If you want the message - keep the exception. It's the error you're looking for. `except Exception as exc` gives you the exception under the variable `exc` and you can output the error message / whatever you need from the exception object. The problem might be that you have foreign relationship constraints that won't allow the `DELETE` to run.

Comment: thanks error is (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  too many connections for role  "YYYY".. what should I do ?

Comment: Reduce the number of connections created by re-using those that you already have. Depending on how your code is structured, make sure you don't create a connection for each query, but just once for the application - and then re-use that connection across queries.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason for the error is because there are foreign keys against the table. In order to be sure, assign the exception into a variable and print it:

```
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

By the way, if you want to quickly delete all of the rows from a table then 
It will be much more efficient to `truncate` the table instead of deleting all the rows:
`truncate table table_name`

Delete is more useful when you want to delete rows under some conditions:
`delete from table_name where ...`